# Transferring ownership of iOS and Android apps

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Can anyone here tell me if the transfer of ownership of an iOS and Android app will change the URL where the app is accessed. I have a client that had a previous developer publish the application for them, I have advised them that they should get their own developer accounts and then have the apps transferred to them. The only concern they have is that they have printed material out there in the world with QR codes that take you to the app store. So they wanted to know if it will all continue to work.

I do release this might be a bit off topic here.

Thanks guys

Comment: For Android it makes no difference. The URL to the playstore is just based off the package name, which will be the same even after transferring. Not sure about iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it says what it will **NOT** do: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

> After an app is transferred, its associated App ID is also transferred
>   to the recipient’s Member Center account. If the transferor’s App ID
>   was a wildcard App ID, it’s converted to an explicit App ID that
>   exactly matches the app’s bundle ID. Associated client SSL
>   certificates for push notifications aren’t transferred. If the app
>   uses Apple Push Notifications service (APNs), the recipient needs to
>   create a client SSL certificate using Member Center to reenable it.
>
> For games, several actions take place depending on whether the app was
>   associated with any other apps. Apps that are part of a cross-app
>   Multiplayer Compatibility Matrix are no longer compatible or appear in
>   the other app’s matrix.
>
> Apps that are part of a Game Center group are removed from the group
>   during the transfer. After the transfer, all leaderboards and
>   achievements revert back to their original status. Leaderboards that
>   were originally a group leaderboard retain the grp. prefix in their
>   identifier.
>
> Leaderboards that were originally single leaderboards but were merged
>   into a group lose the grp. prefix. They also revert back to the
>   original leaderboard IDs they had before the merge. Make sure you
>   update the app build with the new leaderboard IDs so that scores are
>   posted correctly.
>
> If you transfer an app that is part of an app bundle, you will no
>   longer be able to view your app bundle’s history. It is important to
>   make a record of your app bundle information before you transfer the
>   app, as you will no longer be able to access the bundle within iTunes
>   Connect.
>
> If you transfer an app that uses ApplePay, the merchant ID is not
>   transferred along with the app. Transactions continue to be successful
>   as long as the original certificates are valid. However, when you
>   submit an update, the recipient needs to create a new merchant ID on
>   his or her account

So if even your gameplay scores stay intact. I think the URL will stay the same too.

appID is preserved so yeah, go on.